# CSRF token error when submitting different form after ajax login

Tags: ajax, django, django-csrf

Page contains two forms, one for authentification and another for asking a question. The auth form is submitted via an AJAX call and successfully logs in the user. However, if the user submits the question form after login in, it throws "CSRF token missing or incorrect".

main.js

```
$(function() {
    // Submit post on submit
    $('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")
        create_post();
    });

    // AJAX for auth
    function create_post() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "perfil/entrar/", // the endpoint
            type : "POST", // http method
            data : { username : $('#username-text').val(), password : $('#password-text').val() }, // data sent with the post request
            // handle a successful response
            success : function(json) {
                $('#username-text').val(''); // remove the value from the input
                $('#password-text').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            },
            // handle a non-successful response
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
            }
        });
    };


    // This function gets cookie with a given name
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    /*
    The functions below will create a header with csrftoken
    */

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
                // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
                // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    // Open modal dialog for authentification
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myInput').focus()
    });

});
```

index.html

```
            <form method="post" id=class="form-horizontal" action="/perguntar/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                        {{ questionform.title }}
                        {{ questionform.title.errors }}
                        {{ questionform.body }}
                        {{ questionform.body.errors }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                    <div>{{ questionform.orcamento }}</div>
                                    {{ questionform.orcamento.errors }}
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">,00</div>
                                </div>
                                {{ questionform.category }}
                                {{ questionform.category.errors }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Perguntar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </form>

                        <form method="POST" id="login-form">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="username-text">Usuario:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username-text">
                        <label for="password-text">Senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password-text">
                        <input type="submit" value="login" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
                       </form>
```

login_view

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_data = {}
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            response_data['result'] = 'success'
            return HttpResponse(
                        json.dumps(response_data),
                        content_type="application/json"
            )
        else:
            return render(request, 'error.html', {
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {
        })
```

askQuestion_view

```
def perguntar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelThreadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thread = form.save(commit=False)
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                thread.published = True
                thread.creator = request.user
                thread.save()
            else:
                thread.published = False
                thread.creator = None
                thread.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(thread.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ModelThreadForm()
    return render(request, 'perguntar.html', {
                               'questionform': form,
    })
```

I've tried using

```
    data : { 'csrftoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', username : $('#username-text').val(), password : $('#password-text').val() }, // data sent with the post request
```

Instead of

```
        data : { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}', username : $('#username-text').val(), password : $('#password-text').val() }, // data sent with the post request
```

And eliminating the sameOrigin function on main.js. Neither had any effect on the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

That helped me, when i had problems with csrf

http://chevalry.livejournal.com/206466.html

```html
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         function getCookie(name) {
             var cookieValue = null;

             if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                 var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                     var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                 if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                     cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     }
});
```

you can also just disable csrf with decorator
@csrf_excempt
but this is another approach

Comment: Behaviour stayed the same.